# How can I disable automatic send and receive in Outlook for Mac 2011?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-outlook-2010

If go into Tools - Run Schedule - Edit Schedules, send and receive is not checked.

However, Outlook still checks for mail quite frequently.

How can we disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Place.

Check under **Mail Options** → **Send/Recieve**. Thats where you can disable **Sending** and / or **Reciving** per Account.

Alternativly, under the account's **Advanced** details you can change the frequency that the **Auto Send / Recieve** runs. That is per Account though.

Comment: I can't find the Mail Options in outlook 2011. Is it for outlook on PC?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem for my Outlook for Mac 2011:
-  in the menus at the top - go to TOOLS and at the bottom ACCOUNTS...
-  in the ACCOUNTS window, choose the account in the left column, then click on ADVANCED... in the lower right
-  in SERVER, un-check the box for "Sync all IMAP folders every [] minutes"